# How do i limit the number of array elements retrieved by a GET request (REST API JAVA)

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest

Supposedly, My API retrieves JSON having around 100 ids and its respective values.

How do i limit it to first 10 ids with its values?

Is there any JAVA code to limit this?

[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {
"street": "Kulas Light",
"suite": "Apt. 556",
"city": "Gwenborough",
"zipcode": "92998-3874",
"geo": {
"lat": "-37.3159",
"lng": "81.1496"
}
},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
"name": "Romaguera-Crona",
"catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
"bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},

{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ervin Howell",
"username": "Antonette",
"email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
"address": {
"street": "Victor Plains",
"suite": "Suite 879",
"city": "Wisokyburgh",
"zipcode": "90566-7771",
"geo": {
"lat": "-43.9509",
"lng": "-34.4618"
}
},
"phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
"website": "anastasia.net",
"company": {
"name": "Deckow-Crist",
"catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
"bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
}
},

..... "id":100, ...

Comment: Check if the server provides a way, like passing `limit=10` or such in the URL. If not, just stop reading after 10 JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is your best bet for this. So you could pass in some query params to the API call like limit and pageNumber. For example, GET /users?limit=10&page=1 will get you the first 10. If you are using Spring and a database on the backend. Spring Data JPA has pagination built in and it's fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination to apply for the limit and page number.
You can make a fetch request like => fetch(`${url}/_limit=10&_page=1`)
and this will fetch you your desired output

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).